# How to configure WebApp to use SSL

Tags: 2013, claims-based-auth, adfs, ssl, https

I have a Sharepoint 2013 Farm, with a webapp on it that I have configured to authorize users using A trusted idp, in this case I use AD FS WS-Fed so that I can use claims. I want to change from using http (port 80) to https (port 443).

If I go to sts.contoso.com/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon I can sign on as a user from my AD, so ADFS is set up correctly.
However, I think my problem is that I cannot get https to work, and the relying party needs an https connection when accessing the _trust endpoint during sign in. I am basing this on the fact that I am getting a 403 you must be signed in when I try to access my webapp using my http url.

I have followed [this guide](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fabdulwahab/2013/01/20/configure-ssl-for-sharepoint-2013/) for setting up https, and several others. But for some reason I get a "Website not found" every time I try to access it using https, even when all the mapping have been done and IIS configured. It is a simple config and I get no real errors, so can't figure out what is wrong, is there a step missing from this guide, or some common mistake people make?

Are mapping not enough? Do I need to extend to another zone?

Comment: is this internal? on dev enviroment? if so just add to host file as its https it requires DNS for FQDN to resolve... if on dev adding it to host file should fix the issue

Comment: "it" being `https://webappurl.com` ?

Answer (score 2):

Https is requirement for the ADFS authentication. to configure the SSL, here are the steps.

- create a new SSL certificate which has url in the subject name
- Update the IIS Bindings with port 443 and correct ssl cert.( if you have more than one wfe then perform this on all wfe)
- Update the SharePoint alternate access mapping and make sure public url is https.